# How to install phpmyadmin on apache2 ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: apache2, mysql, 20.04, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have installed php7, and mariadb. And I have done these steps that written in this document:

https://websiteforstudents.com/install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04-with-apache/

But I couldn't run phpmyadmin on apache. When I write this in my browser: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, it gives me error 404!!!

[image: could not use phpmyadmin]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

After that you do all the steps that is written in the link that you post, do these steps:

1. At first, download the phpmyadmin from the https://phpmyadmin.net.

[image: Download the phpmyadmin zip file]

2. after that, extract the zip file and rename the extracted directory to `phpmyadmin`.
3. then move the the `phpmyadmin` directory to `/var/www/html` by this command in terminal:

> sudo mv /home/{Username}/Downloads/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin

then, write this in you'r browser:

> http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

and hit ENTER.